# How would Gaseous Form affect a player inside a collapsing tower?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

This already happened in game but the thought occurred to me after.

My party and I were on the third level of a tower, pretty high up. There was a hole in the middle of the floor that we rode a magical air current through to get in which got disabled shortly after. Long story short, our Paladin got cocky, insulted a god (whose tower we were in), and the tower starts collapsing. No idea how much time we have but for various reasons I wanted to investigate the room. Deciding I'd rather not risk death, I immediately left instead.

Now, I didn't realize until after that I had a [Potion of Gaseous Form](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/potion-of-gaseous-form). Would that have been enough to survive inside a collapsing tower?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## *Gaseous form* makes you resistant to nonmagical damage and keeps you from falling

The [Potion of Gaseous Form](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/potion-of-gaseous-form) has the following description:

> When you drink this potion, **you gain the effect of the *gaseous form* spell for 1 hour** (no concentration required) or until you end the effect as a bonus action. This potion's container seems to hold fog that moves and pours like water.

And the [*gaseous form*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gaseous-form) spell description states:

> You transform a willing creature you touch, along with everything it's wearing and carrying, into a misty cloud for the duration. The spell ends if the creature drops to 0 hit points. An incorporeal creature isn't affected.
>
> While in this form, the target's only method of movement is a flying speed of 10 feet. The target can enter and occupy the space of another creature. **The target has resistance to nonmagical damage**, and it has advantage on Strength, Dexterity, and Constitution saving throws. The target can pass through small holes, narrow openings, and even mere cracks, though it treats liquids as though they were solid surfaces. **The target can't fall and remains hovering in the air even when stunned or otherwise incapacitated.**
>
> While in the form of a misty cloud, the target can't talk or manipulate objects, and any objects it was carrying or holding can't be dropped, used, or otherwise interacted with. The target can't attack or cast spells.

It severely limits your ability to interact with your environment while in that gaseous form, but correspondingly, it also protects you from some of the negative effects of having a solid form. You have resistance to all nonmagical damage (e.g. damage from being hit by debris), and you also have advantage on Strength and Dexterity saves (e.g. to avoid being hit or pushed by debris).

So, depending on how your DM would have ruled the fall and how it might have damaged had you stayed and *not* used the Potion of Gaseous Form, the potion might have protected you from the worst effects of the collapse if you had stayed and used it.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on how the DM would have handled the damage inflicted by the collapsing tower.

Gaseous form gives you resistance to damage, not immunity. Presumably, you would have taken literal tons of damage which, even resisted easily could still have been more than enough to drop you to zero HP.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure about the mechanical simulation of "a tower collapsing on top of a play" as you worded it. But I'm pretty sure it's nowhere in the rules, so +1 For the DM call.

Answer (score 1):

As others already said - it depends on the DM how he handle the collapsing tower.

*Gaseous form* gives you resistance to the nonmagical damage (nonmagical damage is halved) and also bonuses to the Strength, Dexterity and Constitution saving throws. Since there usually is a very small chance to survive even in collapsing tower ([for example WTC](http://911research.wtc7.net/sept11/victims/wtcsurvivors.html)), all these benefits are definitely something, which should improve this chance.

But it also depends:
**on the type of the tower** - if it has windows the *Gaseous form* is great :-). It also depends on the material, because big stones could create bigger spaces for survivors. And it also depends on the height of the tower.
**on the type of the damage** - the tower was destroyed by some god so there could be also some other damage types (maybe *force* or *radiant*). And the destruction could also not behave normally (according to the laws of the physics). Cool destruction by god could mean tearing whole tower to pieces and let them rotating in cone before letting everything fall down at once, or something like that.